# Как сгруппировать узлы элементов по атрибуту с помощью XSLT?

Tags: xml, xslt

Дан следующий документ:

```
 <items>
    <item source="a" name="A"/>
    <item source="b" name="B"/>
    <item source="a" name="C"/>
    <item source="c" name="D"/>
    <item source="b" name="E"/>
    <item source="b" name="F"/>
    <item source="c" name="G"/>
    <item source="a" name="H"/>
</items>
```

Как из него с помощью стиля XSL выбрать неповторяющиеся значения из атрибутов, чтобы получилось следующее:

```
<sources>
    <source name="a">
        <item source="a" name="A"/>
        <item source="a" name="C"/>
        <item source="a" name="H"/>
    </source>
    <source name="b">
        <item source="b" name="B"/>
        <item source="b" name="E"/>
        <item source="b" name="F"/>
    </source>
    <source name="c">
        <item source="c" name="D"/>
        <item source="c" name="G"/>
    </source>
</sources>
```

Конкретнее меня интересует как "выудить" a, b, c?

Answer (score 1):

То, о чём вы спрашиваете, называется группировка.

### XSLT 1.0

В XSLT 1.0 для этой цели используют **Группировку Мюнха**.
Группировка Мюнха использует:

1. элемент `<xsl:key>`, который определяет множество
   элементов, сгруппированных по определенному параметру.
2. функцию XPath `generate-id` и тот факт, что при передаче ей
   множества объектов, функция возвращает id только первого из них.

XSLT код для вашего примера следующий:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" exclude-result-prefixes="xsl" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:key name="group" match="item" use="@source"/>

<xsl:template match="items">
  <sources>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="item[generate-id(.) = generate-id(key('group',@source))]" />
  </sources>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="item">
  <source name="{@source}">
    <xsl:for-each select="key('group',@source)">
      <item name="{@name}" sourse="{@source}"/>
    </xsl:for-each>
  </source>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

[Подробное описание работы элемента `<xsl:key>`](https://xsltdev.ru/xslt/xsl-key/) и [функции `generate-id`](https://xsltdev.ru/xpath/generate-id/)

### XSLT 2.0

В XSLT 2.0 появился элемент `<xsl:for-each-group>`, упрощающий подобные группировки:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" exclude-result-prefixes="xsl" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="items">
  <sources>
    <xsl:for-each-group select="item" group-by="@source">
      <sourcename="{@source}">
        <xsl:for-each select="current-group()">
          <item name="{@name}" sourse="{@source}"/>
        </xsl:for-each>
      </source>
    </xsl:for-each-group>
  </sources>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

[Описание элемента `<xsl:for-each-group>`](https://xsltdev.ru/xslt/xsl-for-each-group/)